# Maximum function nesting level reached error in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, civicrm

I am working with Civicrm with Drupal. I created one custom import section. Whenever I submit mapped form it shows this kind of an error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting
>   level of '100' reached, aborting! in
>   C:\wamp\www\crmdev\includes\common.inc
>   on line 290

How can I fix this, and how to reset the nesting level?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you are using xdebug extension
You can do this `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200)`

[xdebug.max_nesting_level](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/basic)

Comment: This was useful for the Commerce Paypal WPS module (http://drupal.org/node/1611570), as well.

Comment: This was also useful for Commerce FedEx module (http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fedex)

Comment: This also happens generall when [addding `collection` types to Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Answer (score 4):

Your code almost certainly has a bottomless recursion, but it's difficult to be sure without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Max nesting level is typically set by zend/xDebug, if infinite recursion occurs without those you will get a segfault instead, you should focus on fixing that infinite recursion instead ...

Comment: Yeah, xdebug is causing this notice, but without xdebug it would be worse. Try to fix it, xdebug will help to pinpoint the exact issue.