# Error with phpunit and Symfony with "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached"

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I already have set the `xdebug.max_nesting_level` to 1000 and it shows up as 1000 in the phpinfo(). But I still get this same error and only when I am testing bundles:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/Dumper/DumperCollection.php on line 81
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:593
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:138
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:186
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:423
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:699
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:767
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:654
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:831
PHP  10. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:958
PHP  11. Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\Controller\DemoControllerTest->testIndex() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:958
PHP  12. Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/Controller/DemoControllerTest.php:13
PHP  13. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:339
PHP  14. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:111
PHP  15. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
PHP  16. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2255
PHP  17. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2975
PHP  18. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2846
PHP  19. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2861
PHP  20. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() /vagrant/public/local.dev/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:139
```

Comment: Do you check `phpinfo` for command line php? `php --ini` ?

Comment: Is [this of any use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103182/maximum-function-nesting-level-reached-error-in-drupal)?

Comment: 100 is a pretty big function depth though - are you sure you need 1000? What's your use case - recursion?

Comment: increase the value of `max_nesting_level` http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Comment: I went into my php.ini file, set the max_nesting_level to 1000, I started my apache2 server, and it shows the max_nesting_level at 1000 in my phpinfo(). But I still get the same error message of '100'.

Comment: I had a similar error because of a failing test. Try to test each Controller, function, etc. only one at the time to see what test fail.